# OTP Verification of Android Studio with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, android-studio-3.0

Is it compulsory to work with the Physical phone while testing the OTP Application in Android Studio with Firebase , or Emulator will work?

If Physical Phone is required then do we have to be on the same network with PC and Testing Phone ?

What are the Prerequisite to run the Project (eg. Internet Access ,Read_SMS etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You must use Physical phone as the OTP will be sent to your through SMS to your actual number. It is not possible through Emulator.

Your app should have internet permission to send OTP request to the Firebase server, and to automatically detect OTP your app must have permission to read SMS.